# more efficient way of remove a few characters from the end of a string

Tags: c++, string

I would like to remove last n characters from a string. I know there is a method called `pop_back()` which can remove the last character. I can use it in a loop like the following, but it doesn't feel efficient.

```
string st("hello world");
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    st.pop_back();
}
```

Wonder if there is more efficient alternative. Thanks.

Comment: I know, it was not a very serious answer (or it would have been an answer). I tried to salvage the comment after realizing `st` was not a `char*`, I guess it is best to remove it altogether.

Answer (score 14):

[`std::string::erase`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) is what you are looking for.

If you wanted to erase the last `n` characters, you would do something like:

```
st.erase(st.length()-n);
```

But make sure you do proper bounds checking.

Comment: Thanks @dwcanillas, I guess you meant `st.erase(st.length() - n)` :-)

Answer (score 3):

[string::substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) would be a better way to do this. You could do it like this:

```
st = st.substr(0, st.length()-n);
```

Comment: `substr` makes a copy, so it isn't necessarily better

Comment: I was more thinking that it would be better than the pop_back technique (in terms of efficiency), i had not thought of your method!

Comment: @Olivier Poulin, thanks for the suggestion. It will work, but my st object is big and I have lots of such objects to do operation on. Wonder if it is possible to do it in-place instead of creating a new object?  Thanks.

Comment: @OlivierPoulin: No, I doubt it would be more efficient than a `pop_back` loop, unless the string is very large and he is removing significantly more than half the characters.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: I was thinking more in terms of time complexity (which would be constant I believe?). I can see how the new objects could be a problem though.

Comment: Well, `substr` would be O(n) in terms of the number of remaining characters (because it has to copy all those characters to the new string), and a `pop_back` loop would be O(n) in terms of the number of characters to be removed. But `substr` also has the additional load of allocating new memory.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: I see, so it wouldn't be more efficient at all, thank you! I guess I have to go rethink some of my own code!

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string st = "hello world";
  int n = 5;
  if (int new_size = st.size() - n; new_size >= 0) {
    st.resize(new_size);
  } else {
    st.clear();
  }
  std::cout << "st = " << st << std::endl;
}
```

Just in case `n` is too big :)

PS. Variable declaration in `if (...)` since [C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if).